# Reverse string operation

Tags: c

The code below gives me the following error:

> incompatible types when assigning to type'char[10]' from type char*
>   lvalue required as decrement operand.

What might cause this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *str1="1234";
    char str2[10];

    str2 = str2 + strlen(str1)-1;          //the str pointer is at 3rd position
    char *p = str2+1;                      //since it has to be a valid string, i assigned pointer p to give the null value at the end of the string.
    *p = '\0';

    while(*(str2--) = *(str1++))            //moving the pointer of str down and pointer of str1 up and copy char from str1 to str2

    printf("%s", str2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

str2 is an array, not a pointer, so on the left hand side `str2 = ...` is not a meaningful C expression.

Either str2 must be a pointer, or use an extra variable, like p, to get the expression

```
char *p = str2 + strlen(str1);
```

Similarly `(str2--)` is not meaningful. Use an extra character pointer to str2, and change that.

Think of an array name as a constant pointer. It can't be changed, but can be used on the right hand side of an `=` in an expression.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, IT WORKS NOW.
i think i messed up with the concept of how to define a string.
So  for example,
char * string = "123";
is different than
char string[] = "123";
?

Comment: Yes, the types of those two `string` variables declared are different. Exactly what the "123" becomes is not the same either. In general, treat the characters pointed to by `char * string = "123"` as constant.

Comment: oh, i am sorry, i am new to this site. 
Now is accepted.  THanks so much!